# Transaction does not roll back using spring

Tags: spring, spring-transactions, rollback

This is a Spring Boot project where in the controllers look like:

```
@Scope(value = "session")
@Component(value = "controller")
@ELBeanName(value = "controller")
@Join(path = "/list", to = "/check/check-list.jsf")
public class controller {
  @Autowired
  private CheckService checkService;
  public String save() {
    checkService.save(checkVO);
}
```

The Service implementation class looks like:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void save(CheckVO checkVO) {
        LOGGER.info("saving check information {}", Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        checkRepository.save(checkVO.getcheck());
        checkImagesRepository.save(checkVO.getImages());
    }
```

Problem is that the call `checkImagesRepository.save(checkVO.getImages());` is failing, and `checkRepository.save(checkVO.getcheck());` is not getting rolled back.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: using oracle XE

Comment: Have you tried if the transaction as well fails to roll back in a unit test with an in-memory database?